# Connecting Intents to intent-filters

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm testing in Oracle's VirtualBox with VM="WSVGA 7.0 Tablet - 4.2.2 - API17"

I am unable to use an Intent to connect to an app with this code:

> ```
>   Intent intent = new Intent("com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE");
>   Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY");
>     //      intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(Uri.parse("file://"), "*/*"); 
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE  dat=file:// typ=*/* }
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE  }
>     //      intent.setType("*/*");
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE  typ=file/* }
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE  typ=*/* }  
>             //  NOTE:  Extra space at end of action  above.  removed below
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE typ=*/* }
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY typ=*/* }
>             //No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY }
> ```

```
    //      startActivityForResult(intent, FolderChosen);
>
```

From my AndroidManifest.xml:

> ```
>    <intent-filter>
>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
>   </intent-filter>
>
>   <intent-filter>
>        <action android:name="com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY" />
>   </intent-filter>
> ```

>
I did get this to work:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(Uri.parse("file://"), "*/*");  //  file:// WORKED

```
// onCreate intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=file:// typ=*/* 
//      flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.example.filechooser/.FileChooser }  <<<<<<<<<<<<<NOTE:  WORKED
```

How should I code an intent-filter that can be chosen by an intent like these:

> Intent intent = new Intent("com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE");
>      Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY");

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I tried for a long time to satisfy the forum's requests about the "contains code" error and after dozens of failures, I quit after the first success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE" />
    <action android:name="com.example.filechooser.PICK_DIRECTORY" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I assume that you'll accept all MIME types, since your  element contains "*/*", so I suggest you omit the  element. By default, if a filter element (ie ) isn't present, Android will match any value.

Comment: Do the action and category entries have to be in the same <intent-filter> group?  I have them in two groups as shown above in my post. The com.estrongs.action package is for the Intent that was supposed to connect to the ES File Manager app.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I added that code as a second intent-filter. Now with two intent-filter groups I can have my app receive requests to select  files or folders.